# How will I implement try or except method in this case?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to bring try or except method in this program, where when an invalid user is searched it should return a message "Invalid user".

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from Admin_Section.models import Distance

class ServiceProviderList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=ProfilecompletioneSerializer
    filterset_class=SnippetFilter
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter,OrderingFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['fullname', 'category','departments','services']
    search_fields = ['fullname', 'category__name','departments__dept_name','services__service_name']

    def get_queryset(self,*args, **kwargs): 
        pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')
        customer = CustomerProfile.objects.get(user=pk)
        Dist=Distance.objects.get(id=1)
        rad=float(Dist.distance)
        radius=rad/111
        query = ProfileCompletion.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(customer.location,radius))
        return query
```

Comment: For your query (after adding `.first()`) if it returns an empty object the user is not on your database or not for the filter used... but I don't know if it is _invalid_  since the criteria is not given.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
For a start, explain why "try -- except" is the proper implementation for your specifications (which we also need).

Comment: Models, serializers, url are needed also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no such user is present the return empty query set

```
def get_queryset(self,*args, **kwargs): 
        pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')

        # ---------- filter first then get the object
        qs = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user=pk)

        if qs.exists():
            customer = qs.first()
        else:
            # return empty queryset
            return qs.none()
        # -----------------

        Dist=Distance.objects.get(id=1)
        rad=float(Dist.distance)
        radius=rad/111
        query = ProfileCompletion.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(customer.location,radius))
        return query
```

Or it's better to make a validation in serializer for queryparameters.

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
    
    def validate(self,attr):
        request = self.context['request']
        pk = request.query_params['']

        # ---------- if user exist then validated else error
        qs = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user=pk)

        if qs.exists():
            return attrs
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("No such User")
        # -----------------
```

Try to implement and comment if faced with any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter() instead of get(). I'm assuming that your API call throws an error Invalid request on this line :

```
customer = CustomerProfile.objects.get(user=pk)
```

Try changing it to :

```
customer_instance = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user=pk).first()
if customer_instance:
      customer = customer_instance.user
else:
      (raise the error which you want to)
```